# Run without auto compile play framework 2.0

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Is there anyway to run my project so that every time I update something it wont auto compile?

I have a friend on the same network who I'd like to get to test the app, but I dont want current changes I'm making to be visible to him.
Maybe something like

```
play "run static"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can "start the application in the background" with

```
play start
```

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/cheatsheet/commandLine